# Difficulties creating USB stick that boots and installs on MacBook circa 2007

Tags: grub, macbook

I am having difficultly trying to install Loki on my MacBook circa 2007. Firstly following the instructions and using Etcher to burn *elementaryos-0.4-stable-amd64.20160921.iso* I created a USB stick that booted fine on my mid 2012 MacBook Pro but not on the 2007 MacBook.

I found this blog post https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266424, and following its instructions of copying bootIA32.efi from Mac Linux USB loader I was able to boot off the USB stick. However when I try installing it always errors with this

> grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error

I've tried about half a dozen times and enabled the internet during installation to no avail.

Comment: I have found a explanation and also solution for the issue though it involves using the 32-bit version https://pommi.nethuis.nl/installing-elementary-os-on-my-late-2006-macbook/

Answer (score 1):

I had this very problem installing on a similar Macbook. For me, it seems that the problem had to do with the way I created the USB stick. I had been following similar instructions.

Ultimately, I got it to work when I setup the USB stick using [Etcher](http://www.etcher.io/), as described in [the Elementary OS setup instructions](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#install-on-macos) on their site.

Comment: What model MacBook do you have? I tried this several times to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) is another neat utility that allows you to select any ISO stored on your USB stick and boot as if it were a CD/DVD.

This has been really key to getting around the 32-bit EFI issue on my mid-2007 MacBook (which it sounds like you have too) and has worked wonders.

I copied the Elementary 6.1 ISO to my Ventoy stick and I’m able to boot into the Elementary Live CD. I also keep the Clonezilla ISO on the stick for recovery and backup.

Give it a shot, it’s sure given my ole little guy new life!